# JQPlot chart not visible in the popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jqplot

I tried to run the following function to create a jqplot in a popup window as results, but the space where the chart is to appear, is blank although I coded it as visible. The pArrData is an array containing the data which it is receiving from a different file.
Can anyone help me out?

```
function ScatterPlot(pDiv,
                 pArrData,
                 pChartTitle,
                 pXAxisTitle,
                 pYAxisTitle)
{

    document.getElementById(pDiv).style.display = "block";

    if (vScatterPlot)
    {
        vScatterPlot.destroy();
    }

    var vChartData = [pArrData];
    var vChartOptions =     
    {
        title: pChartTitle,
        axes:
        {
            xaxis:
            {
                label: pXAxisTitle,
                labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                labelOptions:
                {
                    fontFamily: 'Century Gothic',
                    fontSize: '12pt'
                },
                tickOptions:
                { 
                    fontFamily: 'Century Gothic',
                    fontSize: '10pt'
                },
            }, 
            yaxis:
            {
                label: pYAxisTitle,
                labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                labelOptions:
                {
                    fontFamily: 'Century Gothic',
                    fontSize: '12pt'
                },
                tickOptions:
                { 
                    fontFamily: 'Century Gothic',
                    fontSize: '10pt'
                },
                tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
            }
        },
        seriesDefaults:
        {
            renderer: $.jqplot.BubbleRenderer,
            rendererOptions: 
            {
                bubbleAlpha: 0.6,
                highlightAlpha: 0.8,
                autoscaleBubbles: false,
                showLabels: false
            },
            shadow: true,
            shadowAlpha: 0.05,
        }
    };


    $.jqplot(pDiv, vChartData, vChartOptions).replot();

}
```